# Swap input and print output as column

Tags: java, arrays, char, swap

I have set for myself a task that I am not able to complete. Need help.
What I am trying to achieve is user's input numbers should be swapped by pairs and if there is a comma separated numbers, next swap should output from a new row.
Like if I say: 10000234567,10000234568,10000234569 then output should look like this:
01002043657,
01002043658,
01002043659

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SwapNumbersTest {

public static String swapPairs(String str) {
char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  if(arr[i] == ','){
    i+=2;
  }
  char swap = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
  arr[i - 1] = swap;
}
return new String(arr);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a comma separated numbers: ");
String str = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(swapPairs(str));
}
}
```

what I was thinking, that if there is a char ',' in the way, then all numbers before should be written to an array of chars and be printed out from a new line. Could you please tell, how to achieve such thing?

Also I've noticed that if input numbers are not even then swapping works perfectly, if input numbers are even, ',' comma messes all up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do exactly what you asked:

```
public class SwapNumbersTest {

    public static String swapPairs(String inputString) {
        String swappedNumbers = "";
        String[] arrayOfNumbers = inputString.split(",");
        for (String str : arrayOfNumbers) {
            char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
                if (arr[i] == ',') {
                    i += 2;
                }
                char swap = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
                arr[i - 1] = swap;
            }
            swappedNumbers = swappedNumbers + new String(arr) + ",\n";
        }
        return swappedNumbers.stripTrailing().replaceAll(",$","");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a comma separated numbers: ");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(swapPairs(str));
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

If you didn't want the commas at the end of the line, you simplify it by using:

```
        swappedNumbers = swappedNumbers + new String(arr) + "\n";
    }
    return swappedNumbers.stripTrailing();
```

Comment: thanks. but I use java8, there is no stripTrailing method

Comment: Use trim() instead then.

Comment: Glad I could help. That's a very weird problem to solve.

Comment: thought I was able to solve it using my knowledge. I understand that there are always many ways to solve any problem. thanks for a solution, it solved even the case with even and not even numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you exactly want but to convert the comma-separated numbers to an array of numbers you can do the following.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");
Array<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>;

while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    arr.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
}
```

After doing this I think you can apply the algorithm that you in the array of ints.

Comment: when I apply this, there is no swapping but an array of integers, like if I enter 12,12 output is [12, 12].

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use the Split() function

```
String[] arr = str.split(",");
```

Comment: what if I have char[] arr, not String[] arr? You mean I should use it in main method?

Comment: Exactly, that would eliminate the commas in the character array if you dealt with each arr[index].toCharArray()

Comment: cannot get how to apply this in main method. if i call a function in printout, do I need to convert result to string array?